# Got this error when I click on my BDC service in Central Admin: The full exception text is: Access is denied

Tags: sharepoint-2010, bdc

These are the steps I did under the administrator and farm account:

I go to central admin -> application management -> manage service applications

I click on New-> Business Data Connectivity Service

I enter/select the required fields like name, application pool, application pool identity and click on OK. After a while I see some text that my BDC is created succesfully.

No I see the list with all service applications. When I click on my created BDC service application I got this error:

```
Error An error occurred. Administrators, see the server log for more information.

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.

Correlation ID: 27275209-7fc0-4912-9970-feba5356e9cc

Date and Time: 5/25/2013 9:19:41 PM
```

In the event viewer I see this error:

```
The BDC Service application BDC is not accessible. The full exception text is: Access is denied.
```

Why I get this error? I try it with the farm and administrator account. BUT I have selected another user account for the application pool for this BDC.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the 'Business Data Connectivity Service' is started under central admin -> application management -> Manage services on server.

Under central admin -> application management -> manage service applications, select your 'Business Data Connectivity Service', click on 'Administrator' in the ribbon, and add your current user in full control on the service. You should now be able to open it.